# Algorithm to change an already sampled guitarstring to sound like it was a bit damped by the hand

Tags: filters, audio, algorithms, modulation, sound

I'm trying to simulate the damping of the hand on a guitarstring on an already recorded/sampled open guitarstring sound. I've been trying to use low pass filter and had a moving frequency range but that didn't make it sound like a palm muted string, just the loss of higher frequencies.

Could someone help me find good material on this, that a human could atleast grasp a bit? It's going to be implemented in C++ and I have been searching and found almoust everything about the karplus-strong string algorithm, but that's not what I want.. I do want the damping part implemented on a sample of an already recorded real played string.

My question was first asked here.. I hope that will not be considered as crosslinking now?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667049/algorithm-to-change-an-already-sampled-guitarstring-to-sound-like-it-was-a-bit-d

Comment: Closed as the cross-posted item already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one thing to try: Guitar wave form typically has a sharp on set (the "pluck"), followed by some ringing. You could write an onset or transient detector that finds these onsets. Once you have one, apply a fast exponential decay to the waveform to make the ringing a lot shorter. Find the next onset and repeat. You probably also want a mild low pass filter, just something with negative frequency slope to simulate that the palm damps higher harmonics more than lower harmonics.

Comment: That sounds good, I will try this out.. but could you explain a little bit more about what you mean with the "onsets"?